# I want to put this resulting query into a 3 by 3 html table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the PPM value from my database with the most recent time and print it in my html page after i press the button "display all data"

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","CO");

$sql = "SELECT PPM
FROM sensor S
WHERE Time1=(SELECT MAX(Time1) FROM sensor WHERE ID = S.ID);
";
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

if (!$result) {
    die("database connection failed");
}

echo "<table>";


while($data = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{   

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$data[0]</td>";
    echo "</tr>";


}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

this is printing the results in a single column whereas i want to print the results in a 3 by 3 table
this is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#display").click(function() {                

      $.ajax({    
        type: "POST",
        url: "index1.php",             
        dataType: "html",                   
        success: function(response){                    
        $("#tab").html(response); 
        //alert(response);
        }
      });
    });

  });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>CO Sensor Detector</h2>

<p>Table shows different values of CO sensors</p>

<table align="center">
   <tr>
       <td> <input type="button" id="display" value="Display All Data"> </td>

   </tr>
</table>
<div id="responsecontainer" align="center">
  <table id="tab">

  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

sorry if my question is not in the right format im a noob at asking questions. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to break out the individual values and add them to multiple `<td></td>` elements within each `<tr></tr>`

Comment: @JDunken And it is also good to use `thead` and `tbody` to separate your code.

Comment: @JDunken yes but the thing is the all the values are coming from a single query

Comment: So each `$data[0]` is a string? If so you'll need to do some string manipulation first.

Comment: @JDunken In my database i have id's 1-8 and each has more than one value but $data[0] is giving me each value's most recent time

Comment: According to the documentation `mysqli_fetch_row`  'Fetches one row of data from the result set and returns it as an enumerated array', so the below answer is the correct way of accessing the individual values, although it has some flaws.https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

```
<?php
echo "
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Fila 1</th>
     <th>Fila 2</th>
     <th>Fila 3</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
";
while($data = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{   
    echo "
        <tr> 
          <td> $data[0] </td>
          <td> $data[1] </td>
          <td> $data[2] </td>
        </tr>
    ";
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
?>
```